# I am unable to get the desired response through Stack Exchange API, using Postman

Tags: support, api

I am using this: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#page=3&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow
to get the response.

Is this the correct URI?
I have specified the Auth Key.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's the URL to the documentation, not the API endpoint itself. The correct one is

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?page=3&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

and you can find it by clicking on the link in the Try It widget:

[image]